# Why Haskell disrespects bound identifiers for pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
f x zero = Nothing
f x y = Just $ x / y 
  where zero = 0
```

The literal-bound identifier `zero` simply matches all after the warning `Pattern match(es) are overlapped`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how Haskell's syntax works; **every lowercase-initial variable name in a pattern (re)binds that name**. Any existing binding will be *shadowed*.

---

But even if that weren't the case, the binding for `zero` would not be visible to the first alternative, because of how Haskell's syntax works. A similar thing happens in the following version:

```
f = \v1 v2 -> case (v1, v2) of
                  (x, zero) -> Nothing
                  (x, y)    -> Just $ x / y
                    where zero = 0
```

The **`where` clause only applies to** the **one alternative** that it's part of, not to the whole list of alternatives. That code is pretty much the same thing as

```
f = \v1 v2 -> case (v1, v2) of
                  (x, zero) -> Nothing
                  (x, y)    -> let zero = 0 in Just $ x / y
```

Answer (score 6):

If bound identifiers had different semantics than unbound identifiers in a pattern match, that could be quite error prone as binding a new identifier could mess up pattern matches anywhere that identifier is in scope.

For example let's say you're importing some module Foo (unqualified). And now the module Foo is changed to add the binding `x = 42` for some reason. Now in your pattern match you'd suddenly be comparing the first argument against 42 rather than binding it to `x`. That's a pretty hard to find bug.

So to avoid this kind of scenario, identifier patterns have the same semantics regardless of whether they're already bound somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Because they are very fragile. What does this compute?

```
f x y z = 2*x + 3*y + z
```

Would you expect this to be equal to

```
f x 3 z = 2*x + 9 + z
f _ _ _ = error "non-exhaustive patterns!"
```

only because there's a `y = 3` defined somewhere in the same 1000+ line module?

Also consider this:

```
import SomeLibrary
f x y z = 2*x + 3*y + z
```

What if in a future release `SomeLibrary` defines `y`? We don't want that to suddenly stop working.

Finally, what if there is no `Eq` instance for `y`?

```
y :: a -> a
y = id

f :: a -> (a -> a) -> a
f x y = y x
f x w = w (w x)
```

Sure, it is a contrived example, but there's no way the runtime can compare the input function to check whether it is equal to `y` or not.

To disambiguate this, some new languages like Swift uses two different syntaxes. E.g. (pseudo-code)

```
switch someValue {
  case .a(x)     : ...  // compare by equality using the outer x
  case .b(let x) : ...  // redefine x as a new local variable, shadowing the outer one
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`zero` is just a variable that occurs inside a pattern, just like `y` does in the second line. There is no difference between the two. When a variable that occurs inside a pattern, this introduces a *new* variable. If there was a binding for that variable already, the new variable shadows the old one.

So you cannot use an already bound variable inside a pattern. Instead, you should do something like that:

```
f x y | y == zero = Nothing
  where zero = 0 
f x y = Just $ x / y
```

Notice that I also moved the `where` clause to bring it in scope for the first line.